# Regex Replacing a apostrophe

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var k = "company's dude";
var replaceIt = k.replace(/'s/g,'\'s');
```

I want to replace the apostrophe with the backslash.  The requirement is to create a string with escape character so that it can be used further.  I have tried with above code but no luck.

Comment: What are you escaping them for? Seems like it should maybe cover more than just `'s`…

Answer (score 1):

```
k.replace(/\'/g, '\\') ;
```

it will replace apostrophe with `\`

Comment: `\\\'` was probably intended, and it’s not necessary to escape `'` in the regex literal.